# Issue with google maps API reverse geocoding - postal code returns 2 (prefix) only

Tags: php, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

I have this php to grab data from google servers about specific geolocation.

```
<?php
if ($_GET['latitude'] AND $_GET['longitude']) {
    $lat = $_GET['latitude'];
    $lng = $_GET['longitude'];
    echo json_encode(reverse_geocode($lat,$lng));
}
?>


<?php
//Get STATE from Google GeoData
function reverse_geocode($lat,$lng) {
    $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=$lat,$lng&sensor=false";
    $result = file_get_contents("$url");
    $json = json_decode($result);
    foreach ($json->results as $result) {
        foreach($result->address_components as $addressPart) {
            //print_r($addressPart);
            if((in_array('locality', $addressPart->types)) && (in_array('political', $addressPart->types))) {
                $city = $addressPart->long_name;
            }
            else if((in_array('administrative_area_level_1', $addressPart->types)) && (in_array('political', $addressPart->types))) {
                $state = $addressPart->long_name;
            }
            else if((in_array('country', $addressPart->types)) && (in_array('political', $addressPart->types))) {
                $country = $addressPart->long_name;
            }
            else if(in_array('route', $addressPart->types)) {
                $street = $addressPart->long_name;
            }
            else if(in_array('street_number', $addressPart->types)) {
                $street_number = $addressPart->long_name;
            }
            else if(in_array('postal_code', $addressPart->types)) {
                $postal_code = $addressPart->long_name;
            }
        }
    }

    //return $address;
    return array('country' => $country, 'state' => $state, 'city' => $city, 'street' => $street_number . " " . $street, 'zip' => $postal_code);
    //print_r($json);
}
?>
```

For `?latitude=49.260441796677014&longitude=-123.12049284766846`

This returns:

```
{"country":"Canada","state":"British Columbia","city":"Vancouver","street":"706-750 West 12th Avenue","zip":"V5Z"}
```

Notice zip, it is 3 letter prefix of postal code, not real postal code. Why is this happening? In original json data it seemed I had full postal code. Uncomment `print_r($addressPart);` to see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$addressPart` where the `postal_code` has been taken from contains the type `postal_code`, but when you inspect the response you'll see that it also contains the type `postal_code_prefix`.... and that's what you got. Skip the `$addressPart` when the types contains `postal_code_prefix`

```
else if(in_array('postal_code', $addressPart->types) 
         && !in_array('postal_code_prefix', $addressPart->types)){
  //....
}
```